# fastapi mount not visible in swagger

Tags: swagger, fastapi

for my basic fastapi app

```
from ...
from fastapi.routing import APIRoute, Mount

routes = [
    APIRoute("/", methods=["get"], endpoint=read_root),
    Mount('/square', name='square', routes=[
        APIRoute("/{value}", methods=["get"], endpoint=read_item)
    ])
]

app = FastAPI(routes=routes)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=9999)
```

I can not see `Mount` in auto generated swagger, root `/` is visible and working but not `/square` why ?

Comment: Did you able solve this?